# Regular expression required in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

The following strings: "strAlpha" & "strNum" are my sample string format:

```
String strAlpha = "[fields=A,B,C,D]";
String strNum = "[sales=15,20,16,100,500,54555]";

strAlpha.matches("regex");
strNum.matches("regex");
```

Required regular expression, so the resulted array will only contain the comma separated values of the above string.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Can you show us what is the expected output for the given input ?

Comment: For the "strAlpha", the outputted array will contain the A to its first index and B will be its second index, so on, and same goes for the "strNum", the outputted array will contain the 15 to the first index of array and 20 to it's second and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\[[^=]*=|\]
```

Use `replace` instead to clean up the strings.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tJ2mW5/17